# on hover card should scale out of swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I'm trying to build a swiper just like a Netflix, and trying to achieve the same hover effect. But when I'm hovering over the card, its not scaling out of swiper and stays inside the swiper container.

Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
    />
    <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />

    <!-- Demo styles -->
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #1e1e27;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        /* padding: 0; */
        padding-top: 370px;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        border: 0;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        transform: scale(1);
      }

      .swiper-slide:hover {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px #000000;
        z-index: 50;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        transform: scale(1.5);
        
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
      var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        slidesPerView: 6,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true,
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Current hover effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9keq.png)

And

[Netflix hover effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LESQv.png)

Please review it, and give suggestions.

Its scaling inside the container only and not coming out of swiper.

Comment: okay, it working now, needed to add overflow:visible